# Reduce income tax deduction after being unemployed

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada

The previous month was the first month I have worked this year. I received gross pay of around $3400. However, approximately $500 was deducted for income tax. If I were to continue working for the rest of the year, I would likely get a tax refund since the actual rate I would pay (considering I have not worked for 6 months) would be far lower than the implied rate based on this paycheque alone. Is there a way to reduce the income tax deduction based on this?

For information, I am a resident of Canada. As far as I know, neither [Form TD1](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/cra-arc/formspubs/pbg/td1/td1-21e.pdf) nor filing a Requst to Reduce Tax Deductions at Source would help.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis seems correct; for full-year Canada residents, neither form TD1 nor T1213 provide for reducing withholding to account for only working part of the year.

This [TD1 worksheet](https://hr.acadiau.ca/files/sites/hr/Payroll/Pensions%20%26%20Benefits/2021%20Federal%20TD-1%20Worksheet.pdf) [PDF] does not reduce your withholding, either.

Comment: So then how can withholding be reduced?

Comment: From the available information, your withholding cannot be reduced. Wait for your refund, is what the government seems to be telling you.